# Strange .Net datetime issue

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

Setting with a ternary

```
DateTime filterDate = endDate.HasValue ? endDate.Value : DateTime.Now.AddDays(7);
```

Non ternary

```
DateTime filterDate;
if (endDate.HasValue)
    filterDate = endDate.Value;
else
    filterDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7);
```

If you debug these two statements the value of filterDate will not be the same. Why is this?

In the first example filterDate ends up with a value of 01/01/0001.
In the second example I get the expected result which is filterDate is a datetime 7 days in the future.

EDIT:
At this point I've even tried setting endDate = null just to make sure and here is a screen shot of what happens.
[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/57bef2e50a.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/57bef2e50a.png)

Strangest thing I've ever seen.

Comment: Have you tried putting brackets around your ternary?

Comment: Are you using a nullable DateTime for your endDate ? (i.e. DateTime? endDate)

Comment: Can't see how this might happen. Could you show a small but complete program that demonstrates this? (Making one might give you the answer, too)

Comment: I made the assumption that `endDate` is a `DateTime?`.

Comment: It would have to be to compile, safe assumption I think

Comment: @Nick - Not if he designed his own nullable datetime class with the same member names. :)

Comment: @Jeremy - Ok...you got me there =P

Comment: Do you have optimizations enabled?

Comment: A short but complete program would indeed be the best way of working this out. How certain are you that your debugger is really showing the live data? If you print out `filterDate` and `endDate` to the console instead (with some message proving it's the latest build) can you see the same behaviour?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like endDate is being initialized to DateTime.MinValue, can you show the code where you declare endDate?

Also, an even shorter way:

```
DateTime filterDate = endDate ?? DateTime.Now.AddDays(7);
```

Comment: I tried it that way first and got the same result as the ternary version. I thought maybe the DateTime object didn't support the null coalescing operator.

endDate is a parameter on a mvc controller action. I am not passing anything so it should be null. endDate is null if I quickwatch it.

Comment: Agreed.  Only way I could reproduce the error was to set endDate to min value instead of null.

Answer (score 5):

I was unable to reproduce this. In any case this is the preferred way of doing this:

```
DateTime filterDate = endDate ?? DateTime.Now.AddDays(7);
```